# Java, парсинг строки

Tags: java, строки

Есть строка типа `HaT523HaT524HaT525`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно разбить эту строку так:

```
с1 = "HaT523";
c2 = "HaT524";
c3 = "HaT525";`
```

Comment: Либо вставляйте разделитель между блоками либо split по "HaT" получите массив с блоками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью регулярного выражения. Гибко и возможно любое количество совпадений.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("HaT52\\d");
    String line = "HaT523HaT524HaT525";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    String[] array = new String[3];
    for (int i = 0; matcher.find(); i++) {
        array[i] = matcher.group();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score -2):

Можно воспользоваться методом substring().

```
String s = "HaT523HaT524HaT525";
String c1, c2, c3;
c1 = s.substring(0, 6);
c2 = s.substring(6 , 12);
c3 = s.substring(12);
```